# multidimensional list wont update state

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

how i can update my state in multidimensional list like screen. I can update state in first list level, but if i go on next level, state won't update

```
[0]:MegaFileModel (FileM(id: 714a55f4-d620-4fcb-a723-16af2c6115e3, fileName: Альбомы, extension: folder, preview: null, type: DIRECTORY, uploadUrl: null, serverfileName: null, addDate: 14.12.2021 09:04:14, checked: false))
addDate:"14.12.2021 09:04:14"
checked:false
content:List (3 items)
dir:Map (2 items)
extension:"folder"
fileName:"Альбомы"
id:"714a55f4-d620-4fcb-a723-16af2c6115e3"
preview:null
serverfileName:null
type:"DIRECTORY"
uploadUrl:null
hashCode:92220431
isDirectory:true
runtimeType:Type (MegaFileModel)
```

This is my function which i call every time when i want update state

```
  List<MegaFileModel> getNewContentListState(List<MegaFileModel> state,
      List<MegaFileModel> newState, bool value, String id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
      if (state[i].id == id) {
        newState.add(state[i].copyWith(checked: value, content: []));
      } else {
        newState.add(state[i].copyWith(content: []));
      }
      if (state[i].type == 'DIRECTORY') {
        getNewContentListState(
            state[i].content, newState[i].content, value, id);
      }
    }
    return newState;
  }

  void doPick(bool value, String id) {
    List<MegaFileModel> newState = [];

    state = getNewContentListState(state, newState, value, id);
  }
```

Comment: The sample you gave looks OK, but chances are in your complete app, you mutated "state" instead of making a new list like you did here

Comment: May this happening if i use navigator.push() for enter to down level of my list?